# Web browser communication with native C++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, browser

I have an image processing application that is CPU intensive and is developed in c++ (The images are sourced from webcam in realtime).This application should be run on **client side.**

I want to start, pause, transfer data, and exit the c++ application through a web browser.
So basically my UI will be HTML+Javascript on **client side again.**

I dont want to use NPAPI as my main target browser is G. Chrome which is phasing it out.
I cant use Native Client as it does not support access to webcam because of the sandbox issue.

Is there any way to communicate between c++ and js in the same machine?
I am happy with a windows solution ...
The ideal would be a multi browser solution (chrome,firefox,ie)

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "native client"? What's the sandbox issue? And why can't it access webcam? As for the question: it is not possible without creating extensions.

Comment: Do you want to send a stream of images? Or embedd chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/ ?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows + IE only you could compile to an ActiveX control.

For multi browser will require either recoding in JS - not a trivial under taking or sending the images to a web server - Nodejs could do this - and do you processing there.

Without knowing what you are doing to your images will determine viability of the above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by recording from javascript and passing the data into the native client.

Check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-mediastream for how to record from javascript.